# WPF Printing in XPS Document Writer

Tags: wpf, printing, document, xps, writer

I've implemented a printing feature to print some of the Financial charts in my WPF application by using PrintVisual method. Since the user is free to change his/her window size and/or screen resolution I've use a LayoutTransform, Measure and Arrange methods to make sure that the printed charts gets spread across the entire page evenly irrespective of the size of the application window. All works absolutely well when the user prints on an actual printer or selects PDF Print Driver to print. Layout transform takes effect behind the scene and that shows up in the print, but the user doesn't experience any flicker or change in display on his screen.

The problem comes when the user selects XPS Document Writer. When user does that, the layout on the screen also changes. When the "Save As" dialog box comes up the screen layout changes based on the LayoutTransform provided, which makes the charts go smaller or bigger. The moment user saves the XPS file OR hit cancel on the Save as dialog box the layout goes back to normal. But the strange part is, this happens only when we select XPS Document Writer.

But, user doesn't want to see this.. What can I do to prevent this to happen in the case of XPS Document Writer?

Please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you can make a clone of your canvas or visual prior to applying your transform.  clone is not built-in to wpf UIElements but you can use XamlWriter.Save() and XamlReader.Load to clone via XmlReader.  google "wpf clone UIElement" or I can post some code if you feel that's the way to go.